# xAxis ordinal() does not start in left corner

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have been working on a chart, here is the fiddle:  **https://jsfiddle.net/lucksp/crwb4v5u/**

I have "bins" of data for the Xaxis & bars based on 15 minute increments.

Now that I have the vertical line tooltip, I am noticing the `0:00` time is not the same between the tooltip & the bar chart itself:  the first tick is not 0:00 and the line would say 1:00 (depending on the size of the window since it's variable width based on parent div).

Here you can see a wide window: [image: wide window off by 30]
Here you can see a narrow window: [image: narrow window off by 1:00]
The narrower the window, the more the scale seems to be off.

Example data:

```
[{"hour":"0:00","inProgress":3,"inQueue":0,"sum":3,"maxCapacity":6},{"hour":"0:15","inProgress":5,"inQueue":3,"sum":8,"maxCapacity":5}
```

Setting up the scale:

```
xScale = d3.scale.ordinal()
      .domain(dataSet.map(function(d) {
        return d.hour;
      }))
      .rangeRoundBands([0, innerWidth], 0.1, 0);
```

Setting xAxis:

```
var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
      .scale(xScale)
      .orient('bottom')
      .tickSize(2)
      .tickValues(['0:00', '2:00', '4:00', '6:00', '8:00', '10:00', '12:00', '14:00', '16:00', '18:00', '20:00', '22:00']);
```

Append axis:

```
g.append('g')
  .attr('class', 'x axis')
  .attr('transform', 'translate(0,' + innerHeight + ')')
  .call(xAxis);
```

Create bars:

```
g.selectAll('.bar')
  .data(dataSet)
  .enter().append('rect')
  .attr('class', function(d, i) {
    return 'bar inProgress_inQueue';
  })
  .attr('id', function(d, i) {
    return 'bar_' + i + '_' + d.hour;
  })
  .attr('x', function(d) {
    return xScale(d.hour);
  })
  .attr('y', function(d) {
    return yScale(d.sum);
  })
  .attr('height', function(d) {
    return innerHeight - yScale(d.sum);
  })
  .attr('width', xScale.rangeBand())
```

To calculate the intersection of the tooltip vertical line & data which seems to correctly start at the far left of the chart:

```
.on('mousemove', function(d, i) {
    if (d3.select('.tooltip-table')) {
      d3.select('.tooltip-table').remove();
    }
    var yPos = d3.mouse(this)[1];
    var xPos = d3.mouse(this)[0];
    var leftEdges = xScale.range();
    var width = xScale.rangeBand();
    var j;
    for (j = 0; xPos > (leftEdges[j] + width); j++) {}
    //do nothing, just increment j until case fails
    var selected;
    i = bisectDate(dataSet, leftEdges[j]); // returns the index to the current data item
    if (j < dataSet.length) {
      selected = (dataSet[j]);
    } else {
      return false;
    }
```

I have tried shifting the start of the bars by editing:

```
.attr('x', function(d) {
    return xScale(d.hour) - margin.left; // but this does not work
  })
```

I have 0 outerpadding on the xScale.

What is set up incorrectly to shift the chart on the left & right sides?

Thanks again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just change `.rangeRoundBands` to `.rangeBands` in `xScale` like this:

```
xScale = d3.scale.ordinal()
  .domain(dataSet.map(function(d) {
    return d.hour;
  }))
  .rangeBands([0, width], 0.1, 0);
```

Also notice that `.rangeBands` has another argument, that is the outer padding.

Comment: I KNEW it would be something simple that I swear I tried, but probably also changed something at the same time so it didn't work.  Now I just need to figure out the tooltip itself being offset.  (fiddle updated).

Comment: for tooltip you just need to define width inside `mousemove` like this: `var width = xScale.rangeBand() + margin.left/2;`